# count zeros between 1s in same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I've data like this.

```
ID  IND
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   0
5   1
6   0
7   0
```

I want to count the zeros before the value 1. So that, the output will be like below.

```
ID  IND  OUT
1   0    0
2   0    0
3   1    2
4   0    0
5   1    1
6   0    0
7   0    2
```

Is it possible without pl/sql? I tried to find the differences between row numbers but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: The 2 you show under OUT for ID = 7 doesn't make sense. You show the count only **after** the sequence of zeros ended (attached to an ID with **non**-zero IND), why is that different in the last row of your output?

Comment: @mathguy it's because of an edge case that there are two zeros till end which needs to be considered

Comment: @user14999956 . . . Why not just put the count on all rows?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , how to do that? I don't have sepearate values to partition by and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match_recognize` clause, introduced in Oracle 12.1, can do quick work of such "row pattern recognition" problems. The solution is just a bit complex due to the special treatment of a "last row" with ID = 0, but it is straightforward otherwise.

As usual, the `with` clause is not part of the solution; I include it to test the query. Remove it and use your actual table and column names.

```
with
  inputs (id, ind) as (
    select 1, 0 from dual union all
    select 2, 0 from dual union all
    select 3, 1 from dual union all
    select 4, 0 from dual union all
    select 5, 1 from dual union all
    select 6, 0 from dual union all
    select 7, 0 from dual
  )
select id, ind, out
from   inputs
match_recognize(
  order by id
  measures case classifier() when 'Z' then 0 
                             when 'O' then count(*) - 1
                             else          count(*)     end as out
  all rows per match
  pattern  ( Z* ( O | X ) )
  define   Z as ind = 0, O as ind != 0
);

        ID        IND        OUT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          0
         2          0          0
         3          1          2
         4          0          0
         5          1          1
         6          0          0
         7          0          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat this as a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can define the "islands" by the number of "1"s one or after each row.  Then use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ind = 1 or row_number() over (order by id desc) = 1
             then sum(1 - ind) over (partition by grp)
             else 0
        end) as num_zeros
from (select t.*,
             sum(ind) over (order by id desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If `id` is sequential with no gaps, you can do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ind = 1 or row_number() over (order by id desc) = 1
             then id - coalesce(lag(case when ind = 1 then id end ignore nulls) over (order by id), min(id) over () - 1)
             else 0
        end)
from t;
```

I would suggest removing the `case` conditions and just using the `then` clause for the expression, so the value is on all rows.

Comment: Both solutions ignore the special requirement that if the last row has IND = 0, the output for that row must show the count of zeros for that group. See my question to the OP and his answer. Moreover, the second query doesn't count zeros, it counts all the rows in a group (so, besides fixing the "last row with IND = 0" issue, you must also fix the counts - subtract 1).